# Django ORM: order by minimal value from m2m depending on specific value

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have 4 models:

**User**, multiple **Place**(s) where he lives. Each **Place** have multiple nearby **MetroStation**(s). 
Then, I have time in road (**MetroTimes**) between all each to each metro stations.

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Place(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    metro_stations = models.ManyToManyField('geo.MetroStation', related_name='places')

class MetroStation(models.Model):
    pass

class MetroTimes(models.Model):

    metro_station_1 = models.ForeignKey(MetroStation, related_name='metro_stations_1')
    metro_station_2 = models.ForeignKey(MetroStation, related_name='metro_stations_2')

    time = models.IntegerField()
```

The task is to sort all users by time in road (**MetroTimes**) to specific **MetroStation** from closest **MetroStation** among all **User's** **Place's**)

And the magic I can't deal:

```
specific_metro_station = MetroStation.objects.get(id=1)

User.objects.all().order_by(closest_metro_station_in_closest_user's_place_by_metro_time_to=specific_metro_station)
```

Big Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using Django's [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) and [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/)

Code in My case:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Min, When
from django.db.models import CharField, Case, Value, When, IntegerField

current = MetroStation.objects.get(id=1)

users = User.objects.all().annotate(
    time=Min(
        Case(
            When(
                places__metro_stations__metro_stations_1__metro_station_2=current,
                then=F('places__metro_stations__metro_stations_1__time')
            ),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
).order_by('time')
```